# Share your device screen with UIActivityViewController

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

as the question suggests, I'm looking for a way to share the current device screen when using UIActivityViewController. Here's my code so far.

```
@IBAction func buttonShareTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let textToShare = "Here's my text to be shared!"

    // Generate the screenshot
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    var image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    var imageToShare = UIImage(named: "\(image)")

    if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "http://mywebsite.com/")
    {
        let objectsToShare = [textToShare, imageToShare, myWebsite]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

        // Excluded Activities Code
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]

        self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The code above produces the following error from the line beginning Let objectsToShare:

`'_' is not convertible to 'UIImage?'`

which I believe is because imageToShare is currently returning nil.

Thanks in advance.

edit: In the above example the image variable returns the value below but imageToShare is returning nil so I guess the issue is in that line.

`<UIImage: 0x7ffc85c12f80>, {320, 504}`

Comment: as long as the `+named:` returns an _optional_ `UIImage` only, you need to unwrap first before you'd like to use it, maybe... (source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is strange but I didn't need to convert the image into a named UIImage. My code works as expected when I do the following:

`if let imageToShare = image {...`

Yet the following returns nil

`if let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "\(image)") {...`

so I guess what is returned from UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() requires no further converting.

Answer (score 1):

maybe my first comment helps on you already, but I would add a bit more for that.

---

if you are sure the image is always a valid object and it can be unwrapped *every time*, you can be brave to use that:

```
var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "\(image)")!
```

this solution would cause a direct crash if the `image` is `nil` and you want to unwrap it, so you can do this **only** when you are 100% sure the image is always valid in runtime;

---

otherwise that is the proper way:

```
if let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "\(image)") {
    // you have the image unwrapped properly, it can be used for anything.
    // ...
}
```

and if the `image` cannot be unwrapped (=`nil`), you are able not to add to your `objectToShare` array conditionally.

---

*NOTE: that is a quite good example why the actual type of the variable should be defined explicitly every time* (`var imageToShare: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "\(image)"`), *because you'd presume its value is* unwrapped, *however it was an* optional *only.*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, your suggestions make it a lot more robust, I appreciate it. One problem remains though is that the imageToShare var is returning nil, with your updates it will no longer cause a break, however I'd like to be able to figure out the correct code required to take a screenshot. Any ideas? Thanks!